# creating vector using new operator

Tags: c++

I have an assignment and the question is **"write a function that creates a vector of user-given size M using new operator"**

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int user_size;
    std::cin >> user_size;
    int *p = new std::vector<int> g5(user_size);
    delete p;

    return 0;
}
```

pls give me any advice how can I improve the code(obviously my knowledge improves too) and this code doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: I suspect that "vector" in the question is not `std::vector`, but another name for "array". Creating a `std::vector` object with `operator new` is unusual.

Comment: @Salvage you are **right**, can you tell me if the code is right a

Comment: That `g5` doesn't belong there. To create a single object with `operator new` you give its type and an initializer: `new std::vector<int>(user_size)`. But the type of that expression is not `int*`, so `int *p = ...` isn't right. `int *p = new int[user_size]` seems like a better fit.

Comment: "int * p" should be "std::vector<int>* p" (the comment markup killed the *, corrected, thx Pete)

Comment: @Sebastian -- there is no `int p` in the code. Yes, if the code is supposed to use `std::vector`, it should probably be `std::vector<int> p(user_size)`, but since there's a requirement to use `operator new`, that doesn't meet the specification.

Comment: This code does not compile since a `std::vector<int>*` is not a `int*`. Furthermore you're not using a function to create the vector and declaring an identifier in the operand of the `new` operator like this is not allowed. Furthermore if it's indeed the vector that's supposed to be created with the `new` operator, you're being taught bad C++: there's no reason to allocate the vector on the heap instead of the stack here. A function `std::vector<int> MyFunction(...)` yield similar performance to a function `std::vector<int>* MyFunction(...)`. The former simplifies resource management.

Comment: With new int[user_size] you would need delete[] as array variant. Best is of course just std::vector<int> without new

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear, what is meant here by *vector*. Moreover, the assignment says nothing about the type of the data. If *vector* is meant to be an *array* of `M` then the following

```
int*array = new int[M];
```

is the appropriate command (here assuming `int` as data type). In this case, you will need to delete the array later using the `delete[]` rather than plain `delete`, i.e.

```
delete[] array;
```

On the other hand, if *vector* refers to `std::vector`, then

```
std::vector<int> *pvec = new std::vector<int>(M);
```

is appropriate. However, this is really bad code, as `std::vector` under the hood allocates its data using `new` anyway, implying that this type of code generates a double reference and unnecessary memory allocation. Now you must use plain `delete` for destroying the object:

```
delete pvec;
```